# Finding number of number pairs with given difference

Tags: java, array, complexity

`pairs()` is a function which returns the total number of combinations whose difference is `k`.

```
     static int pairs(int[] a,int k) {
        int counter=0;
         for (int i : a.length ) {
           for(int j=i+1;j<a.length;j++){
                 if(a[i]-a[j]==k||a[i]-a[j]==-k){
                   counter++;
                 }
                }
           }

 return counter;
}
```

`a` is an array of numbers and `k` is the difference of numbers that are given by user.  I have to find the total number of combinations with a difference of `k`.  I have done this code, but I want a more optimized code.

Comment: Could you add a couple of example inputs/outputs?

Comment: `for (int i : a.length )` this is a compiler error, which affects *the rest* of the code...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Current complexity is \$O(n^2)\$, you can accomplish this with \$O(n \space log \space n)\$ instead by sorting the array first and then loop through the elements.

Let's say that you know that the array is sorted, and the array is for example `4 8 15 16 23 42` and you want to find the diff `7`:

Let's initialize two variables, `lowIndex`, `highIndex` to both `0`.

- Now we compare index 0 to index 0, i.e. 4 and 4. It's less than the diff value (7) so we increase `highIndex`
- Compare index 0 to index 1, 4 vs. 8, still less than 7, so `highIndex++`
- Compare index 0 to index 2, 4 vs. 15, that's more than 7, so `lowIndex++`
- Compare index 1 to index 2, 8 vs. 15, that's exactly 7, so we have a match and we do `highIndex++`
- Compare index 1 to index 3, 8 vs. 16, that's more than 7, so `lowIndex++`
- Compare index 2 to index 3, 15 vs. 16, that's less than 7, so `highIndex++`
- Compare index 2 to index 4, 15 vs. 23, that's more than 7, so `lowIndex++`
- Compare index 3 to index 4, 16 vs. 23, that's exactly 7, so we have a match and we do `highIndex++`
- Compare index 3 to index 5, 16 vs. 42, that's more than 7, so `lowIndex++`
- Compare index 4 to index 5, 23 vs. 42, that's more than 7, so `lowIndex++`
- Compare index 5 to index 5, 42 vs. 42, that's less than 7, so `highIndex++`
- `highIndex` has reached the end of the array, return the number of matches found.

Comment: You need the handle the case of elements being equal too, though.  That means an array with 2x duplicates such as `4 4 8 8 15 15 16 16 23 23 42 42` should return 4x the number of combinations as without duplicates.

Comment: @JS1 Right, that would be the next step. There are a few different ways to handle that, I think.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a Java expert, but one suggestion would be to subtract once in the loop:

```
static int pairs(int[] a, int k) {
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
            int diff = a[i] - a[j];
            if (diff == k || diff == -k) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }

    return counter;
}
```

This should not *hurt* performance, as you already do the subtraction no less than once, and in the case of `a[i]` being less than `a[j]` it should *help* performance.

You could also precompute `-k` to save on the negation of it. (Not that this is an expensive calculation.)

```
static int pairs(int[] a, int k) {
    int counter = 0;
    int negK = -k;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
            int diff = a[i] - a[j];
            if (diff == k || diff == negK) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }

    return counter;
}
```

I can't guarantee that will have performance impacts, though.

---

Also, another note, the `for (int i : a.length)` *does not appear* to be valid Java.

The correct version is `for (int i : a)` (according to [this Oracle document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)), which *is not actually what you are trying to do*. To fix that to match with the rest of your code, you should be using `for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)`.

---

Lastly (and I already did this for you) you should definitely clean up the formatting of your code. It's very hard to read as it stands. Clearing up your indentation makes the code a lot easier to follow.

Comment: How about using `Math.abs(diff) == k`?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Something tells me that would be slower. A call to `Math.abs` cannot be free. (I don't have a Java environment setup, so I can't vouch whether or not it is.)

Comment: `Math.abs(diff)` will come with another packages  that wil degrade performance