# Numbers, pairs, and a difference

Tags: java, algorithm, rags-to-riches

Problem statement:

> Write a function which returns the total number of combinations whose difference is `k`.
>
> For example, `4 8 15 16 23 42` and the difference `7` has 2 pairs, `8, 15` and `16, 23`.

---

I liked the [Finding number of number pairs with given difference](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/101475/31562) question so much (despite its brokenness) that not only did I [review it](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/101480/31562), but I also decided to write up my own implementation of it (following the approach I described in my review). I was intrigued by [this comment:](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101475/finding-number-of-number-pairs-with-given-difference/101480#comment185577_101480)

> You need the handle the case of elements being equal too, though. That means an array with 2x duplicates such as `4 4 8 8 15 15 16 16 23 23 42 42` should return 4x the number of combinations as without duplicates. - [JS1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/58193/js1)

When a pair is found, I count how many numbers are matching at `lowIndex` and `highIndex` respectively, and then calculating how many pairs there are.

**NumberPairsDiff.java**

```
public class NumberPairsDiff {

    public static int pairsWithDifference(int[] input, long difference) {
        int[] sorted = Arrays.copyOf(input, input.length);
        Arrays.sort(sorted);

        int pairsFound = 0;

        int lowIndex = 0;
        int highIndex = 0;

        while (lowIndex < sorted.length && highIndex < sorted.length) {
            long current = (long) sorted[highIndex] - sorted[lowIndex];
            if (current < difference) {
                highIndex++;
            } else if (current > difference) {
                lowIndex++;
            } else {
                // Find out how many values are equal at `highIndex`
                int highMatching = findEqual(sorted, highIndex);
                highIndex += highMatching;

                if (difference == 0) {
                    // 1+2+3+4+5+...+n = 0.5x^2 + 0.5x
                    int add = (int)(0.5f * highMatching * highMatching + 0.5 * highMatching);
                    pairsFound += add;
                    lowIndex += highMatching;
                } else {
                    // Find out how many values are equal at `lowIndex`
                    int lowMatching = findEqual(sorted, lowIndex);
                    lowIndex += lowMatching;
                    pairsFound += lowMatching * highMatching;
                }
            }
        }

        return pairsFound;
    }

    private static int findEqual(int[] sorted, int index) {
        int matching = 1;
        while (index < sorted.length - 1 && sorted[index] == sorted[index + 1]) {
            index++;
            matching++;
        }
        return matching;
    }

}
```

Obligatory parametrized unit test, **NumberPairsDiffTest.java**:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class NumberPairsDiffTest {

    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
                {new int[]{ 4, 4, 8, 8, 15, 15, 16, 16, 23, 23, 42, 42 }, 4, 4},
                {new int[]{ 4, 4, 8, 8, 15, 15, 16, 16, 23, 23, 42, 42 }, 7, 8},
                {new int[]{ 4, 4, 8, 8, 15, 15, 16, 16, 23, 23, 42, 42 }, 0, 18},
                {new int[]{ 1 }, 0, 1},
                {new int[]{ 2, 2 }, 0, 3},
                {new int[]{ 3, 3, 3 }, 0, 6},
                {new int[]{ 4, 4, 4, 4 }, 0, 10},
                {new int[]{ 2, 2, 4 }, 0, 4},
                {new int[]{ 1, 4, 7, 11, 14, 17 }, -3, 4},
                {new int[]{ 1, 4, 7, 11, 14, 17 }, 5, 0},
                {new int[]{ Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE }, (long)(Integer.MAX_VALUE) * 2L + 1L, 1},
        });
    }

    @Parameterized.Parameter(value = 0)
    public int[] input;

    @Parameterized.Parameter(value = 1)
    public long diff;

    @Parameterized.Parameter(value = 2)
    public int expected;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        String string = String.format("Array %s with diff %d", Arrays.toString(input), diff);
        assertEquals(string, expected, NumberPairsDiff.pairsWithDifference(input, diff));
    }

}
```

**Primary concerns**

- Readable, understandable code?
- Missed edge-cases?
- Better approaches?

Comment: `{new int[]{ 4, 4, 8, 8, 15, 15, 16, 16, 23, 23, 42, 42 }, 4, 4}` <-- That really confuses me but I don't see a better way for it

Comment: I actually found the return of all elements, note necessarily unique a *lot* harder!

Answer (score 10):

The basic algorithm you use is logical, and well presented. The general style is standard, and I see no issues there. I believe the algorithm can be changed slightly to make the comparison code simpler, but the performance will still be comparable.

I looked for edge cases I would have expected, specifically relating to large differences, but you appear to have covered that well. Unfortunately, your pair-counts for `diff == 0` are all off. For example, your third test case:

> ```
> {new int[]{ 4, 4, 8, 8, 15, 15, 16, 16, 23, 23, 42, 42 }, 0, 18},
> ```

should have a count of 6, and not 18. There are only 6 pairs with difference 0. The pair at index 0, and 1, is the same pair as index 1 and 0, so you can't double (or, for some reason triple) count them.

This also applies to cases like: `{new int[]{ 1 }, 0, 1},`.... you have an input array of just a single element... but you have 1 pair with diff 0? Really???

There is one small performance improvement related to how far you need to iterate in the loop - you have: `while (lowIndex < sorted.length && highIndex < sorted.length) {` but that can be just `while (highIndex < sorted.length) {` since `lowIndex` is always less than or equal to `highIndex`. This is particularly confusing if your input `difference` is negative.

For some reason, and I can't explain it, I prefer `left` and `right` for those variable names too... `lowIndex` seems not-quite-right, but I understand it anyway. Just a niggly thing.

Additionally, there are a few places where I would do things in a more Java-8 way. Let's deal with the smaller items first...

### Small things

Consider this code:

> ```
> int[] sorted = Arrays.copyOf(input, input.length);
> Arrays.sort(sorted);
> ```

I would (now) use the following:

```
int[] sorted = IntStream.of(input).sorted().toArray();
```

As for negative difference input values, I would just handle that as an up-front special condition. The count of pairs with a negative difference will be the same as the count with a positive difference and the same magnitude. Just convert negative difference to positive, and handle the Long.MIN_VALUE special case.

### Algorithm

I would alter the algorithm a little. I would have a simple scan of the data to count value duplicates, and store that count in a separate array. With that data structure, the search for duplicates later is much easier. Consider this:

```
    if (input.length <= 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    
    int[] sorted = IntStream.of(input).sorted().toArray();
    
    // remove and count duplicate values
    int[] counts = new int[sorted.length];
    int size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
        if (sorted[i] != sorted[size]) {
            sorted[++size] = sorted[i];
        }
        counts[size]++;
    }
    size++;
```

The above code ends up with a simpler data set to navigate. Unfortunatley, it makes the case where diff==0 a little more complicated... you need to use factorials for that, and not simple products. (Edit, I extracted that logic completely)....

Still, I put the whole method together as:

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class NumberPairsDiff {

    public static int pairsWithDifference(int[] input, long difference) {
        
        if (input.length <= 1) {
            return 0;
        }
        
        if (difference == Long.MIN_VALUE) {
            return 0; 
        }
        
        if (difference < 0) {
            difference = -difference;
        }
        
        int[] sorted = IntStream.of(input).sorted().toArray();
        
        // remove and count duplicate values
        int[] counts = new int[sorted.length];
        int size = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
            if (sorted[i] != sorted[size]) {
                sorted[++size] = sorted[i];
            }
            counts[size]++;
        }
        size++;

        if (difference == 0) {
            int pairsFound = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                pairsFound += factorial(counts[i] - 1);
            }
            return pairsFound;
        }

        int left = 0;
        int right = 0;
        int pairsFound = 0;
        
        while (right < size) {
            long diff = (long)sorted[right] - (long)sorted[left];
            if (diff < difference) {
                right++;
            } else if (diff > difference) {
                left++;
            } else {
                pairsFound += counts[left++] * counts[right++];
            }
        }
        return pairsFound;

    }

    private static int factorial(int n) {
        int f = n;
        while (--n > 1) {
            f *= n;
        }
        return f;
    }

}
```

The above function fails a bunch of your test cases because it produces the correct results ;-)

Comment: for negative diffs, `lowIndex` does go higher than `highIndex`, best way to fix would probably be to do `Math.abs(difference)`. The `diff == 0` case also compares elements against themselves (in fact, all `diff != 0` does that too but then it will never be true). I let my algorithm determine my requirements, instead of thinking about the requirements.

Comment: And then you let your output values from your code be used to set the expected values of your tests? That's the wrong way around..... you should write your tests and then ensure the code gives the right values.

Comment: No, actually I did write my tests and then changed the code to match the test. I just had the wrong idea of what I wanted (or maybe rather, a bad idea of *why* I wanted it that way)

Comment: `if (difference == Long.MIN_VALUE) return 0;`.<-- `0 - Long.MIN_VALUE` is a perfectly valid pair?

Comment: @BrunoCosta - the inputs are all integers, but the difference is a long. - the maximum difference between two integers is \$2^{32} - 1\$ whihc is way smaller than long's max value. The `== MinValue` check is just there to prevent a possible issue where the user specifies MIN_VALUE for the long argument, and that cannot be made positive in binary (the negated value of `MIN_VALUE`is still `MIN_VALUE`). So, you state: *`Long.MIN_VALUE` is a perfectly valid pair?* ....  I challenge you to find me two `int` values that would be a valid pair ;-)

Comment: @rolfl what you are saying basically is that you should have written `difference > int.MAX_VALUE * 2l - 1`

Comment: Well, not really, @BrunoCosta There needs to be a check for negative input differerences too. I think what it really needs is a comment (indicating "why").

Answer (score 3):

First of all I am confused about the test cases for `difference == 0`. If I've only one input, i think the number of pairs is 0 (not 1) because I've no pair. If I've two equal values, i think the number of pairs is 1 (not 3)! And so on....

Apart from that, I tried to use a Map/Hashtable for counting the equal input values (so that there's no need for the `findEqual`-method.

```
public static int pairsWithDifference(final int[] input, final long difference) {
    Hashtable<Integer, Integer> equalCounter = new Hashtable<Integer, Integer>();
    for (int singleInput : input) {
        Integer counter = equalCounter.get(singleInput) == null ? 0 : equalCounter.get(singleInput);
        equalCounter.put(singleInput, counter + 1);
    }
    // equalCounter: Hashtable with input as key and amount of equal inputs as value

    // int[] sorted = Arrays.copyOf(input, input.length);
    Integer[] sorted = new Integer[0];
    sorted = equalCounter.keySet().toArray(sorted);
    Arrays.sort(sorted);

    int pairsFound = 0;

    int lowIndex = 0;
    int highIndex = 0;

    while (lowIndex < sorted.length && highIndex < sorted.length) {
        long current = (long) sorted[highIndex] - sorted[lowIndex];
        if (current < difference) {
            highIndex++;
        } else if (current > difference) {
            lowIndex++;
        } else {
            // Find out how many values are equal at `highIndex`
            int highMatching = equalCounter.get(sorted[highIndex]);
            int add;
            if (difference == 0) {
                // 1+2+3+4+5+...+n = 0.5x^2 + 0.5x
                add = (int) (0.5f * highMatching * highMatching + 0.5 * highMatching);
            } else {
                // Find out how many values are equal at `lowIndex`
                int lowMatching = equalCounter.get(sorted[lowIndex]);
                add = lowMatching * highMatching;
            }
            highIndex++;
            lowIndex++;
            pairsFound += add;
        }
    }

    return pairsFound;
}
```

Comment: but *with* the `findEqual` method, there's no need for a `HashMap`.

Comment: The idea of the test cases where `difference == 0` was that each number is also equal to itself. Maybe my own requirements there are not the best, but that would be very easy to change (I'd just decrease `highMatching` by `1` before calculating `add`)

Comment: also, *if* you're gonna use a Map, use `HashMap`. `Hashtable` is horribly outdated.

Comment: There's no special reason why I used `Hashtable` but the one that I don't need/want null values in my map - so indeed I could have used HashMap instead.

Comment: And yes, the decrease of `highMatching` by `1` would be the only change needed to fit with my interpretation of the requirement.

Comment: I honestly find no reason for a `Map` at all. I haven't benchmarked, but I believe it will be just as fast as my original code (maybe even slightly slower).

Comment: My reason was readability of the code. This way, I only increment the `lowIndex` and `highIndex` by `1` instead of a value which has to be calculated/counted. I personally find it easier to understand, that I just go to the next higher number (instead of keeping in mind, that there are possible multiple equal values and that I have to step with the correct step size). But of course that are small differences to your algorithm and maybe a matter of taste.

Answer (score 3):

## Floating point police

As a proud member of the *Floating Point Police*™, I'm issuing you citation for unnecessary use of floating point here:

```
    int add = (int)(0.5f * highMatching * highMatching + 0.5 * highMatching);
```

First of all, the equation is wrong.  The plus sign should be a minus.  But second of all, you don't need floating point since \$n*(n-1)/2\$ is always integral.  If you are afraid of integer overflow, you can cast to `long`:

```
    long add = (long) highMatching * (highMatching - 1) / 2;
```

Comment: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/5942/27975

Comment: The equation isn't wrong for the requirements I put of myself. The fact that those were not very logical requirements is another issue...

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg True, `1+2+...+n` is in fact the equation you solved.  It's just that you needed to stop at `n-1`.

Answer (score 2):

> `{new int[]{ 4, 4, 8, 8, 15, 15, 16, 16, 23, 23, 42, 42 }, 4, 4}` <-- That really confuses me but I don't see a better way for it –  [Ismael Miguel](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/53773/ismael-miguel)

Thought I'll provide some advice on this...

One can explore a `Builder` approach, something like:

```
private static class TestCaseBuilder {
    private final int[] values;
    private long diff;
    private long expected;

    private TestCaseBuilder(int... values) {
            this.values = values;
    }

    static TestCaseBuilder given(int... values) {
        return new TestCaseBuilder(values);
    }

    TestCaseBuilder andDifference(long diff) {
        this.diff = diff;
        return this;
    }

    TestCaseBuilder expect(long expected) {
        this.expected = expected;
        return this;
    }

    Object[] build() {
        return new Object[]{ values, diff, expected };
    }
}
```

It becomes (arguably) more readable:

```
// was
return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
        {new int[]{ 4, 4, 8, 8, 15, 15, 16, 16, 23, 23, 42, 42 }, 4, 4},
...

// now
return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
        TestCaseBuilder.given(4, 4, 8, 8, 15, 15, 16, 16, 23, 23, 42, 42)
                        .andDifference(4).expect(4).build(),
...
```

Alternatively, drop the `Builder` in the name and treat this as *the* testing payload:

```
public class NumberPairsDiffTest {
    @Parameterized.Parameter
    public TestCase testCase;

    // ...

    @Test
    public void test() {
        String string = String.format("Array %s with diff %d", 
                            Arrays.toString(testCase.values), testCase.diff);
        assertEquals(string, testCase.expected, 
                NumberPairsDiff.pairsWithDifference(testCase.input, testCase.diff));
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also have the `.expect` method return a `TestCase` directly.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg yeah, but I wanted to showcase the `TestCase`-as-a-payload alternative too without touching the code again, so I thought I can leave that conclusion up to the reader (as you did). :)

Answer (score 1):

My review goes along with most points provided by @rolfl namely about repeating pairs.
Although IMO `factorial` does not suffice for repeating pairs, 
it's true that in the array `[4, 4, 4]` you only have the pair `(4, 4)` but I considered all the possible
combinations to be valid pairs thus `(4(0), 4(1))`, `(4(0), 4(2))` and `(4(1), 4(2))` are different pairs.

But you can easily have your own approach on how to count those scenarios.

IMO the worst about your code is that you are mixing two different algorithms, the binary search, and the count of pairs.
I suggest strongly to separate those.

```
public static int[] binarySearch(int[] list, int elem)
{
    return binarySearch(list, elem, 0, list.length - 1);
}

public static int[] binarySearch(int[] list, int elem, int left, int right)
{
    int idxFirst = -1;
    int auxRight = right;
    int auxLeft = -1;
    while (left <= right)
    {
        int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
        if (list[mid] > elem)
        {
            right = mid - 1;
        }
        else if (list[mid] < elem)
        {
            left = mid + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (list[right] > elem)
            {
                auxRight = right + 1;
            }
            right = mid - 1;
            idxFirst = mid;
            auxLeft = auxLeft < 0 ? mid : auxLeft;
        }
    }
    int idxLast = binarySearchLast(list, elem, auxLeft, auxRight);
    return new int[]{idxFirst, idxLast};
}

public static int combinations(int elements, int length)
{
    return factorial(elements, elements - length + 1)/factorial(length, 2);
}

private static int factorial(int n, int stop){
  if(n<=stop){return n;}
  return n * factorial(n-1, stop);
}

private static int binarySearchLast(int[] list, int elem, int left, int right)
{
    int idxLast = -1;
    int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
    while (left <= right && mid > -1)
    {
        if (list[mid] > elem)
        {
            right = mid - 1;
        }
        else if (list[mid] < elem)
        {
            left = mid + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            left = mid + 1;
            idxLast = mid;
        }
        mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
    }
    return idxLast;
}


public static int pairsWithDifference(int[] input, long difference) {
    if(input.length <= 1){
      return 0;
    }

    int[] sorted = Arrays.copyOf(input, input.length);
    Arrays.sort(sorted);

    int pairsFound = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < sorted.length; ++i){
        int[] interval = binarySearch(sorted, (int)(difference + sorted[i]));
        if(interval[0] > -1){

          boolean sumsTodifference = ((long)sorted[i] - sorted[interval[0]]) == difference || 
              ((long)sorted[interval[0]] - sorted[i]) == difference;

          if(sumsTodifference){
              if(sorted[interval[0]] == sorted[i]){
                //we are on a sequence with repeated numbers
                pairsFound += combinations(interval[1] - interval[0] + 1, 2);
                i = interval[1] + 1;
              }else{
                pairsFound += interval[1] - interval[0] + 1;
              }
          }
        }
    }

    return pairsFound;
}
```

Those are the tests according to what I would expect:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    Object[][]  tests = new Object[][]{
            {new int[]{ 4, 4, 8, 8, 15, 15, 16, 16, 23, 23, 42, 42 }, 0l, 6},
            {new int[]{ 1 }, 0l, 0},
            {new int[]{ 2, 2 }, 0l, 1},
            {new int[]{ 3, 3, 3 }, 0l, 3},
            {new int[]{ 4, 4, 4, 4 }, 0l, 6},
            {new int[]{ 2, 2, 4 }, 0l, 1},
            {new int[]{ 1, 4, 7, 11, 14, 17 }, -3l, 4},
            {new int[]{ 1, 4, 7, 11, 14, 17 }, 5l, 0},
            {new int[]{ Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE }, (long)(Integer.MAX_VALUE) * 2L + 1L, 1},
    };
    for(Object[] test : tests){
        int pairs = pairsWithDifference((int[])test[0], (long)test[1]);
        System.out.println(pairs + "=" + (int)test[2]);
    }
}
```