# Pair, differences and correlations

Tags: python, algorithm, iteration

This has a couple of twists which I personally found rather awkward... All code can be downloaded in a read-to-run format from [here](https://github.com/flipdazed/Hybrid-Monte-Carlo/blob/master/test/test_acorrMapped.py)

### The problem

Consider a classic interview question: *"Find given pairs with a specific difference in a given array"*

Here I impose the unique conditions:

- The array is non-decreasing
- Consider [*combinations*](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/%7Ewgreen4/Math124S07/PermuCombinations.pdf) not *permutations* `arr[i],arr[j] == arr[j],arr[i]`
- To make the operation more interesting, calculate the [*correlation function*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/167874/82081) defined as `((arr[i]-mean_arr)*(arr[j]-mean_arr)).mean()`
- Consequently, when no pairs are found the return should be `np.nan`

### Benchmark Naiive Example

This will scale terribly but is easy to read

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
diff = 0.1                 # difference
arr = np.linspace(0,1,11)  # input array example

def naiiveFn(arr, diff, tol=1e-5):
    # get all combinations of the list with itself
    all_pairs = list(itertools.product(*[list(arr)]*2))
    all_pairs = np.asarray(all_pairs)
    # select all valid pairs
    pairs = all_pairs[np.abs(np.diff(all_pairs, axis=1).ravel() - diff) < tol]
    # calculate the correlation function ((pair1_i - mean)*(pair2_i - mean)).mean()
    result = np.prod(pairs- arr.mean(), axis=1).mean()
    return result
```

**The target is speed speed speed!!!**

### Test cases

In this section I provide two examples for accuracy and performance testing

#### Performance

A good benchmark case to challenge performance requires a lot of varied separations but must hold the non-decreasing property.

The following provides a good example, where we want performance to scale well with `n`

```
diff = 0.1; n = 2000
perf_arr_small = np.cumsum(np.around(np.random.exponential(diff, n), 1))
```

and when run for our basic function

```
%timeit naiiveFn(perf_arr, diff)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.85 s per loop
```

A more challenging case is `n > 20000`: I ran `naiiveFn` at `n=20000`, went for a coffee break and it was still going when I came back!

### Accuracy

Obviously a function is totally useless if if doesn't do what it is supposed to. This will test six cases that I picked to exhibit particular behaviours these are generated by running `genTestData()` from below

```
from scipy.special import binom 
import numpy as np # it's beyond me that neither np.binom or math.binom exist

def testFn(results, test, res_pairs=None):
    """Takes in two arrays of your function results and compares to test data
    If you pass the pairs you found to res_pairs it will also neatly display those

    Required Inputs
        results :: list :: list of results from test function
        test :: list :: list of test cases to compare against

    Optional Inputs
        res_pairs :: list of lists/np.arrays :: list of pairs that were found
    """
    outcomes = ["Failed","Passed"]

    print "\nTest outcomes..."
    if res_pairs is None: res_pairs = len(test)*[None]
    for i,(r,t, pairs) in enumerate(zip(results, test, res_pairs)):
        try:
            np.testing.assert_almost_equal(r,t)
            passed = True
        except:
            passed = False
        pr = "  test:{} :: {} :: res: {:7.4f} actual: {:7.4f}".format(i+1, outcomes[passed], r, t)
        if pairs is not None: pr += " pairs: "+" ".join(["{:d}x({:3.1f} {:3.1f})".format(n,i,j) for (i,j),n in Counter(tuple(p) for p in pairs).iteritems()])
        print pr
    pass

def genTestData():
    """Generate test data
        test_cases :: list of 6 test arrays each of length 10
        test_set1  :: the four test cases with 0.1 separation
        test_set2  :: the four test cases with no separation
    """
    n = 10

    # Examples to catch most common errors
    a = np.array([0.1]*10)         # case of everything the same
    b = np.linspace(0.1, 1, 10)    # everything spaced equally
    c = np.array([0.1]*5+[0.2]*5)  # intersection of two repeating segments
    d = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3] + [0.4]*5 + [0.5]*2) # a mash-up
    e = np.array([0.4]*3 + [0.5]*3 + [0.6]*3 + [5]) # series of identicals
    f = np.asarray([0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8] + [0.9]*3 + [1.0]*2) # no match then matches


    # a quick function used a fair bit in the case of equal incrementation
    equalSpacing = lambda seg, mean, sep: np.sum((seg[:seg.size-sep]-mean)*(seg[sep:]-mean))
    nCr52 = binom(5,2)  # ways of choosing n from r where order matters
    nCr32 = binom(3,2)
    dm = d.mean()      # both means used a lot so declaring saves space
    em = e.mean()
    fm = f.mean()

    # the test cases for 0.1 separation
    sep = 0.1
    t1a = np.nan
    t1b = equalSpacing(b, b.mean(), 1)/float(n-1)
    t1c = (0.1-c.mean())*(0.2-c.mean()) #*5**2/5**2
    t1d = (equalSpacing(d[:3], dm, 1) + (.3-dm)*(.4-dm)*5. + 5.*2*(.4-dm)*(.5-dm))/(2.+5.+2.*5.)
    t1e = ((0.4-em)*(0.5-em)*3.*3. + (0.5-em)*(0.6-em)*3*3)/(3.*3.+3.*3)
    t1f = ((0.8-fm)*(0.9-fm)*3. + (0.9-fm)*(1.0-fm)*2.*3.)/(3.+2.*3.)

    # test caess for 0 separation
    sep = 0.0
    t2a = 0.0
    t2b = np.nan
    t2c = ((0.1-c.mean())**2*nCr52 + (0.2-c.mean())**2*nCr52)/(nCr52+nCr52)
    t2d = ((0.4-dm)**2*nCr52 + (.5-dm)**2)/(nCr52+1)
    t2e = ((0.4-em)**2*nCr32 + (.5-em)**2*nCr32 + (0.6-em)**2*nCr32)/(3*nCr32)
    t2f = ((0.9-fm)**2*nCr32 + (1.0-fm)**2)/(nCr32+1)

    cases = [a,b,c,d,e, f]
    test_set1 = [t1a, t1b, t1c, t1d, t1e, t1f]
    test_set2 = [t2a, t2b, t2c, t2d, t2e, t2f]
    return cases, test_set1, test_set2
```

### Useful

- [Numbers, pairs, and a difference](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/102086/114425)
- [Finding number of number pairs with given difference](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101475/finding-number-of-number-pairs-with-given-difference)
- [Count all distinct pairs with difference equal to k](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-pairs-difference-equal-k/)

Comment: (You know back not to be more advanced than front (even use that when `abs(diff-sep) < tol`): don't check for `back < n` to control the loop.) Re missing cases: specified difference 1 and a sequence like `1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4…` looks challenging - one pair or six?

Comment: I might be missing something, but it looks to me that the code is broken? `l_ans` and `r_ans` are both just floats, so there isn't a `mean()` method that can be called on their product.  If that's the case, then this is off topic and I'm voting to close.

Comment: you caught out a teaser for my actual code sample. I am doing autocorrelations in quantum field theory that take `arr` as a tensor `(n,M)` where `n` are the number of MCMC samples and `M` is the N-dim lattice

Comment: Added a test data set which shows my implementation is actually useless! I am currently debugging! I'll also be double checking the test data is correct

Comment: couple of bugs just editing my post

Comment: Thanks, that was actually what I was editing! In know its a dumb way of doing it but I was trying to make it easier for for people to refer to specific variables in comments by assigning them static names. I've added a direct download for all the code if you want to mess about with it. I need to address why it is not matching my test cases as it seemed to work last night

Comment: I think the only way to do this is to increment the front pointer and sweep the back pointer. The condition of sweeping the back pointer just needs to be handled properly

Comment: (Just pondering whether turning values into pairs (value, multiplicity) is beneficial.)

Comment: so that's actually what the naiive method does and you get all nasty things like segmentation errors etc. I've implemented the sweep method I'm just refining it a little and adding another test array that is needed

Comment: I added a test case for when there are no pairs and then pairs are found. This required a line at the end of `if abs(arr[bssp+1]- arr[bssp]) > tol: bsfp = front` I think this now works perfectly so I'll move my answer to an answer so anyone can rate it

Comment: ([naïve](http://en.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=naiive)?) me: `turn values into pairs (value, multiplicity)` AMcF:`that's actually what the naiive method does` - I don't speak python fluently, but doesn't `itertools.product(list, list)` produce a _list of all internal pairs_? I was thinking of `1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4…` -> `(1, 2), (2, 3), (4, …`.

Comment: ah right! so a case for `from collections import Counter`? That's an interesting thought! How would you implement that? Would it generate binomial coefficients for each duplication?

Comment: I'm quite confused about whether this runs as intended or not. What are the 4 odd cases you're talking about?

Comment: Hi I missed out an edit to the language in the accuracy section. It started as 4 tests and I realised that there needed to be two more cases to catch all irregularities. Just run `genTestData()` to grab the tests. If you want to download the whole lot then just go to my repo and run the file I've linked :)

Answer (score 1):

### My Own Attempt

I am fairly confident that this can pass as an answer now to the problem and is ready for anyone to review and offer speed improvements

#### Performance

Here are the benchmark tests. I also ran at various other parameters to verify the scaling behaviour as shown in the figure below

```
diff = 0.1; n = 2000
arr = np.cumsum(np.around(np.random.exponential(diff, n), 1))
mean = arr.mean()
%timeit attempt(arr, diff, mean, n)

n = 20000
arr = np.cumsum(np.around(np.random.exponential(diff, n), 1))
mean = arr.mean()
%timeit attempt(arr, diff, mean, n)

n = 2000000
arr = np.cumsum(np.around(np.random.exponential(diff, n), 1))
mean = arr.mean()
%timeit attempt(arr, diff, mean, n)

## -- End pasted text --
100 loops, best of 3: 2.52 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 25.1 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 2.52 s per loop
```

[image]

#### Accuracy

```
Start separation of 0.1

Test outcomes...
  test:1 :: Passed :: res:     nan actual:     nan pairs: 
  test:2 :: Passed :: res:  0.0642 actual:  0.0642 pairs: 1x(0.8 0.9) 1x(0.3 0.4) 1x(0.1 0.2) 1x(0.7 0.8) 1x(0.6 0.7) 1x(0.4 0.5) 1x(0.5 0.6) 1x(0.2 0.3) 1x(0.9 1.0)
  test:3 :: Passed :: res: -0.0025 actual: -0.0025 pairs: 25x(0.1 0.2)
  test:4 :: Passed :: res:  0.0056 actual:  0.0056 pairs: 1x(0.2 0.3) 10x(0.4 0.5) 5x(0.3 0.4) 1x(0.1 0.2)
  test:5 :: Passed :: res:  0.2025 actual:  0.2025 pairs: 9x(0.4 0.5) 9x(0.5 0.6)
  test:6 :: Passed :: res:  0.0606 actual:  0.0606 pairs: 3x(0.8 0.9) 6x(0.9 1.0)

Start separation of 0.0

Test outcomes...
  test:1 :: Passed :: res:  0.0000 actual:  0.0000 pairs: 1x(0.1 0.1)
  test:2 :: Passed :: res:     nan actual:     nan pairs: 
  test:3 :: Passed :: res:  0.0025 actual:  0.0025 pairs: 1x(0.1 0.1) 1x(0.2 0.2)
  test:4 :: Passed :: res:  0.0032 actual:  0.0032 pairs: 1x(0.5 0.5) 1x(0.4 0.4)
  test:5 :: Passed :: res:  0.2092 actual:  0.2092 pairs: 1x(0.5 0.5) 1x(0.6 0.6) 1x(0.4 0.4)
  test:6 :: Passed :: res:  0.0669 actual:  0.0669 pairs: 1x(1.0 1.0) 1x(0.9 0.9)
```

### Code

This code is a shortened version without the overhead debugging. For a longer version which generated the accuracy test see my repository for [`test.test_acorrMapped`](https://github.com/flipdazed/Hybrid-Monte-Carlo)

```
def attemptShort(arr, sep, mean, n, tol=1e-7, **kwargs):
    """Shortened version for Stack Exchange"""
    if sep == 0: # fast exit for 0 separations
        # faster than np.unique as latter requires a mask over counts>1
        unique_counts = np.asarray([(v,c) for v,c in Counter(arr).iteritems() if c>1])
        if not unique_counts.size: return np.nan    # handle no unique items
        combinations = binom(unique_counts[:,1],2)  # get combinations
        return ((unique_counts[:,0]-mean)**2*combinations).sum() / combinations.sum()

    front = 1   # front "pythony-pointer-thing"
    back  = 0   # back "pythony-pointer-thing"
    bssp  = 0   # back sweep start point
    bsfp  = 0   # back sweep finish point
    ans   = 0.0 # store the answer
    count = 0   # counter for averaging
    new_front = True # the first front value is new
    while front < n:            # keep going until exhausted array
        new_front = (arr[front]-arr[front-1]>tol)  # check if front value is a new one
        back = bsfp if new_front else bssp         # this is the magical step

        diff = arr[front] - arr[back]
        if abs(diff - sep) < tol: # if equal subject to tol: pair found
            if new_front:
                bssp  = bsfp    # move sweep start point
                back  = bsfp    # and back to last front point
                bsfp  = front   # send start end point to front's position
            else:
                back  = bssp    # reset back to the sweep start point
            while back < bsfp:  # calculate the correlation function for matched pairs
                count+= 1
                ans  += (arr[front] - mean)*(arr[back] - mean)
                back += 1
        else:
            if abs(arr[bssp+1]- arr[bssp]) > tol: bsfp = front

        front +=1
    return ans/float(count) if count > 0 else np.nan # cannot calculate if no pairs
```

### Applications

Hybrid Monte Carlo - [see my repository](https://github.com/flipdazed/Hybrid-Monte-Carlo)

My implementation can be found in the function [`correlations.acorr.acorrMapped`](https://github.com/flipdazed/Hybrid-Monte-Carlo/blob/master/correlations/acorr.py).

I assign a map of separations to the MCMC samples that were generated by solving Hamiltons Equations of Motion for exponentially distributed trajectories. Hence, unlike normal autocorrelations, these are separated by an exponentially fictitious length defined by the Equations of Motion.

Comment: I think this can be improved by creating a hash table of all repeated elements - if this can be done in `O(n)` then all the `back` sweeps can be eliminated and replaced by multiplicities derived from the hash table - based on @greybeard 's comments

Comment: To further add to this comment above. A key problem with a hash table approach is that it requires an *exact* lookup. When `numpy` stores the arrays it stores them with a floating point error. Thus an exact match in a hash table is not really possible.